# how does LSTM and GRU gates decide which word to keep in the memory

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit, nlp

the update gate in a GRU decides which word to keep in the cell or to be clear what is the cell state.
how does the update gate in gru decide when to be close to 1 and when to be close to 0?
Basically, how does it decide to keep a word and not to keep a word? Thanks

Comment: I added an answer but it's unclear what your current understanding and knowledge of GRUs of as well as exactly what your confusion is. Let me know if my answer doesn't address what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what background research you've done in the question. Perhaps a google search for gru tutorials might turn up some helpful blogs. Here is [one](https://medium.com/paper-club/grus-vs-lstms-e9d8e2484848).

Remember though the cell state is updated using weights which are optimized the same way any other neural network weights are, with backpropagation. [This](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/) is a great blog to help explain how RNNs (GRU is one specific example) are set up and how backpropagation through time is used to update the weights. The weights of the GRU then determine how the cell state is updated.